# Can I use conversation messages stored on Blockchain

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, microsoft-azure

I'm new to Blockchain and exploring if I can safely store textual and media content in the transaction. This will help me with the following outcomes

1. I can have a safe, secure storage of contents between users
2. I can share it later with any other user at ease
3. There is no public views allowed and no moderation on these contents
4. I can also reward the user based on the content he had shared with me.

If there's transaction size limits, how best can we leverage the power of Blockchain.

This would be a private Blockchain and I am exploring on using Azure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there might be significant differences between each different blockchain, as a general principle, they are certainly not intended to store media content by design.

As for the textual content, you can store it in the blockchain but you have to manage all the encryption in order to restrict who can access to it, and it can be somehow complex if data can be retrieved by different groups of users (if this would only be peer to peer, you could use asymmetric encryption). I am assuming you would be using a private blockchain without gas fees per transaction; otherwise, the approach would be unfeasible in case of a high volume of communications.

One way you could use the blockchain is to manage the data access: when you provide tokens to users, these tokens could be used as a pass to access data (either text or media) which is stored off-chain (out of the blockchain, for instance, in Azure).

Just as a reference, the closest thing for managing text communication using a blockchain is the project [Status](https://status.im/), but I am aware it took a few years for them to reach a production-ready application. Perhaps you can also get some ideas from there.

Comment: Can you share any use-cases related to using Azure and data access tokens from ethereum that you have came across. I am also searching for this meanwhile.

Comment: The big cloud providers are actually providing private blockchains that are already integrated with their services (i.e. AWS or Azure), so you can develop Blockchain As a Service. You can have a look at this article: https://medium.com/mledger/kickstart-your-ethereum-journey-on-microsoft-azure-part-2-41773ce8a2c2   I haven't done any blockchain development inside these cloud platforms so can't provide that much feedback, but they seem to give you the link between the blockchain features totally integrated with their storage services for media/text.

Comment: I was able to come up with few resources like https://res.mdpi.com/d_attachment/applsci/applsci-10-02011/article_deploy/applsci-10-02011.pdf and https://docs.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/architecture/solution-ideas/articles/blockchain-workflow-application These might be of help for others also